# Explanation Behind Combinatorial Enumeration Algorithm

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Can any combinatorists here perhaps enlighten me about the rational behind this technique for enumerating combinations of size $l$ drawn from elements of a set of symbols of size $k$?

Please forgive the terminology as they were taken from a paper that I had prepared.

Basically, I have found a way to iterate over finite length combinations whose elements are drawn from finite set of elements using a single index, moduli, exponentiation, and the integer floor function. I would like an explanation behind why this works.

Additionally, I have not taken any coursework solely dedicated to combinatorics.

Illustration of a general case:
[image: The general scheme of the algorithm.]

Illustration of a specific case of three elements ("a","b","c") and combinations of length two (represented as a string of length two):
[image: A specific instance of the algorithm for three elements ("a","b","c") and combinations of length two.]

Comment: Your method works for the same reason that base-$k$ representation works, since $W_0,W_1,\dots,W_{\ell-1}$ are the first $\ell$ digits of $j$ in base $k$. This is one of those things that everyone understands, so the explanation of why it is true is rarely written out.